# ArduinoWebsocket Server only receive 1 packet but I can't figure out why?

Tags: websocket, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have a project running currently using ESP32 with Websockets. I have an ESP32 with the camera set up as a server and forwarding image data to a mobile app. The mobile app receives this data successfully without issue and I can view the image on a webpage. The mobile app should then forward that data packet to another ESP32, which is again running as a Websocket server, where it will be displayed on a TFT.

I have this section of the project working also, but I can only receive the first image. After that the mobile app throws errors stating the websocket connection failed however neither the mobile app or ESP32 close the websocket.

Changing timers/delays had a little improvement whereby the mobile app would forward more data packets, but the ESP32 never received them - or at least the Serial Monitor output did not give indication of further packets being received.

I have looked online some already and found mention of a difference between readBlocking and readNonBlocking commands, however the specific library I am using only has the option to readBlocking. There are also examples of a similar project online using the ESP32 and the same library, receiving data repeatedly over Websocket. The code from these projects is very similar to my own so I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Any assistance with whether I am using the Websocket protocol would be much appreciated, or if anyone can see anything in the code which could be causing the problem I would be so grateful.

Thanks

Code for context, written in the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#include <TJpg_Decoder.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid_here";
const char* password = "password_here";
const char* imageFileName = "/camimage.jpeg";

using namespace websockets;
WebsocketsServer server;
WebsocketsClient client;

TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();         // Invoke custom library
boolean SDInited = false;

bool tft_output(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t* bitmap)
{
   // Stop further decoding as image is running off bottom of screen
  if ( y >= tft.height() ) return 0;

  // This function will clip the image block rendering automatically at the TFT boundaries
  tft.pushImage(x, y, w, h, bitmap);


  // Return 1 to decode next block
  return 1;
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  delay(1000);

  if(!SPIFFS.begin(true)){
    Serial.println("SPIFFS init failed!");
    while(1) yield();
  }else{
    SDInited = true;
    Serial.println("SPIFFS init success");
  } 

  Serial.println("Beginning WiFi");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //Initialise WiFi
  delay(500);

    for(int i = 0; i < 15 && WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED; i++) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
  }

  IPAddress IP = WiFi.localIP(); //Define variable IP for checking
  Serial.print("IP Address : ");
  Serial.println(IP); //Print IP address for Websocket connection
  
  Serial.println("Beginning TFT");
  delay(1000);
  tft.begin(); //Initialise TFT
  tft.setRotation(3); //Landscape
  tft.fillScreen(random(0xFFFF)); //Place random colour data on screen
  delay(1000);
  Serial.flush(); //Clear serial buffers
  delay(1000);
  tft.setSwapBytes(true); // Swap colour bytes for image clarity

  TJpgDec.setJpgScale(1); //Do not change scale

  TJpgDec.setCallback(tft_output); //Call rendering function in to decoder
  
  server.listen(80); //WS port 80

  //Check server is available, and report on Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Is the Server available? -> ");
  if(server.available()!=0){
    Serial.println("Yes");
  }
  else
  { 
    Serial.println("No");
  }
       
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  Serial.println("Start of loop...");
  if(SDInited){
    Serial.println("SDInited");
    WebsocketsClient client = server.accept(); //Allow connection
    
    if(client.available()){

      WebsocketsMessage msg = client.readBlocking(); //Read received data in to msg
      boolean isSaved = fileWrite(imageFileName, msg); //Pass msg and file name in to fileWrite process
      if(isSaved){

        Serial.println(msg.data()); //Write data to Serial Monitor for cehcking
        uint32_t t = millis();
        Serial.println(t); //Write a time stamp to Serial Monitor for checking

        // Get the width and height in pixels of received image
        uint16_t w = 0, h = 0;
        TJpgDec.getFsJpgSize(&w, &h, imageFileName); // Note name preceded with "/"
        Serial.print("Width = "); Serial.print(w); Serial.print(", height = "); Serial.println(h);
      
        TJpgDec.drawFsJpg(0, 0, imageFileName); //Write image to TFT

      }
  }
 }
}

boolean fileWrite(String name, WebsocketsMessage content){
  SPIFFS.remove("/camimage.jpeg");
  File file = SPIFFS.open(name.c_str(), "w");
  if(!file){
    String errorMsg = "Can't open file";
    Serial.println(errorMsg);
    return false;
  }else{
    file.write((const uint8_t*) content.c_str(), content.length());
    file.close();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: During image processing webSocket is'nt listening because ESP is busy. if process take too long time it can throw network time-out.  Also avoid `Serial.println(msg.data());` as it's blocking until serial buffer empty. Timestamps can help to find problem reasons, as ram usage.

Comment: Thanks, processing takes around 100ms based on previous tests- I believe the link should stay awake for up to 250ms based on some documentation I saw. That said, would there be a way to prevent a network time-out, I assume it is based on some form of timer?

Comment: So not seem to be timeOut problem. Best way to debug things is to progressively comment out code parts until code loop well (or vice-versa).  Using serial.print is not allways helpfull because in case of crash, last messages are lost.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, the error was caused by the use of an if() statement controlling communication. Once the process was completed and the if() statement exited, communications with the client could not be re-established. Opting instead for a while() loop held the communication active and the process could run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your recommendations, the error was caused by the use of an if() statement. Once the process was completed and the if() statement exited, communications with the client could not be re-established when the loop() restarts because it was never actually closed by the client. Opting instead for a while() loop held the connection active and the process could run correctly. If connection was closed by the client, the while() loop would exit and the ESP32 would aim to re-establish a connection as required.